# Computer Modern font with R's cairo_pdf

Tags: r, graphics, fonts

I can use `CM Roman` via the `extrafont` package, but it fails with `cairo_pdf`. Is it possible to use the Computer Roman font with `cairo_pdf`?

Comment: @Axeman that seems to be using `pdf` not `cairo_pdf` unless I am mistaken

Comment: Oh I see, yes..

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use greek symbols that do not show up with pdf() but only with cairo_pdf(). At the same time I would like to use CM Roman. No suggestions at all?

Comment: Facing the same issue, has anyone found a way to use Greek symbols in CM Roman font?